# Protoc on mac os --goout is not recognized as an flag

Tags: protocol-buffers, protoc, grpc-go

i'm running osx

```
$ uname -rsv
Darwin 21.2.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.2.0: Sun Nov 28 20:28:54 PST 2021; root:xnu-8019.61.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
```

installed with brew and from binaries both didn't work

```
$ brew install protobuf
```

```
$ protoc --version 
libprotoc 3.19.4
```

i'm getting an error when i'm trying to generate code using protos and grpc it says --go-out unknown flag

```
$ protoc -I protos/ protos/curr.proto --go-out=plugins=grpc:protos/curr
Unknown flag: --go-out
make: *** [protos] Error 1
```

After installing  from pre-compiled binaries ( didn't work )

```
$ PB_REL="https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases"
$ curl -LO $PB_REL/download/v3.15.8/protoc-3.15.8-linux-x86_64.zip
$ unzip protoc-3.15.8-linux-x86_64.zip -d $HOME/.local
$ export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin"
```

`-bash: /$HOME/.local/bin/protoc: cannot execute binary file`

Any idea how to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need the protoc-gen-go and protoc-gen-grpc plugins as stated on [gRPC Go Quickstart](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

even after installing protoc-gen-go and protoc-gen-grpc plugins kept giving an error

```
protoc --go_out=plugins=grpc:./protos  --go_opt=paths=source_relative protos/currency.proto
--go_out: protoc-gen-go: plugins are not supported; use 'protoc --go-grpc_out=...' to generate gRPC
```

somehow this's in mac doesn't work due to no support for [plugins](https://github.com/golang/protobuf/issues/1070)

to solve you need to add

`option go_package = ".";` to your .proto file

then running should solve it .

```
protoc --go_out=.  --go_opt=paths=source_relative  --go-grpc_out=. --go-grpc_opt=paths=source_relative  ./protos/myproto.proto
```

Answer (score 0):

This error: `--go_out: protoc-gen-go: plugins are not supported; use 'protoc --go-grpc_out=...' to generate gRPC` is due to the fact that plugins are not supported in `--go_out` anymore.

you will need to use the `--go-grpc_out` flag to generate your gRPC-related code. So you can do something like:

```
protoc --go_out=./protos --go-grpc_out=./protos  --go_opt=paths=source_relative protos/currency.proto
```

Also note that adding `option go_package = ".";` kind of suppress the purpose of packages. what you can do instead is passing the module options, just like:

```
protoc --go_out=. --go-grpc_out=. --go_opt=module=example.com/m --go-grpc_opt=module=example.com/m protos/currency.proto
```